# How do I make it so an account's User Account Control dialog appears without a password prompt?

Tags: uac, ease-of-access

On my primary account (the original one with which I installed Windows), when a User Account Control dialog appears, I have simply "Yes" and "No" buttons. However, when my partner (to whom I have given a separate Administrator account) sees one on this same machine, it asks for their password as well.

Is there any way I can make it so that they only have to press "Yes" or "No" like I do?

---

Below is a screenshot from my Settings app, showing that all accounts on the machine are set to "Administrator"

[image: Three accounts, each reading "Administrator" beneath them]

---

Below are examples of each (not mine; from others on the Internet whom have shared such dialogs)

[image: A dialog asking if it's okay to allow Microsoft Windows to make changes to the device, with options "Yes" and "No"]
[image: A dialog asking if it's okay to allow User Account Control Settings to make changes to the device, with a password field and options "Yes" and "No"]

Comment: Doesn’t sound like the second account is actually an Administrator on the machine.  Your account isn’t by chance the built-in Administrator?

Comment: @Ramhound for each account, I have the option to make them an "Administrator" or a "Standard User". I have set each and every account on the machine to "Administrator". My partner selects their account from the UAC dialog and types their password, so they are indeed an admin. I've attached a screenshot. I hope I 'm missing something, but as far as Windows is showing my, that account is actually an Administrator on the machine.

Comment: Why is the Administrator account (3rd one) not marked as Local account?

Comment: @harrymc because it's a Microsoft account. That's not the account in question

Comment: Some questions: (1) Did you install Windows using a Microsoft account and then added the Local accounts? (2) What are they doing that generates the UAC dialog? (3) Is the password that they enter the one for your Microsoft account?

Comment: @harrymc (1) Yes. (2) Installing programs, moving files to protected folders, and other things that admins do. (3) No; it's their local account password. They don't know any of my passwords.

Comment: What is your UAC setting?

Comment: @harrymc what do you mean?

Comment: @harrymc here is the User Account Control Settings control panel: https://i.imgur.com/WHB6QBN.jpg

Comment: Noted. More: Running `gpedit.msc`, in *Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options*, is "User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode" set to "Prompt for consent on the secure desktop"? If not, set it and reboot.

Comment: @harrymc both _Security Settings_ "folders" are empty

Comment: My specification of where are these policies was incomplete. The specification should have been: *Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options*.

Comment: @harrymc it is set to "Prompt for consent on non-Windows binaries"

Comment: Try to set it to "Prompt for consent" and reboot.